# Incorporating flexibility exercises into StrongLifts workout

Tags: workout-routines, flexibility, stronglifts

I am currently doing the Stronglifts 5x5 workout program, and I was wanting to incorporate a stretching routine into my workout that would both:

1. Supplement my lifts by stretching the used muscle groups
2. Increase my overall flexibility (sit reach, splits, etc.)

Given these goals, what should my stretch routine look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it separately from or after your lifting. Stretching before lifting will decrease the force you will be able to produce.

As far as supplementing your lifts, you only need to stretch if you can't use proper form or get full range of motion. Additional stretching will not help your lifts (won't necessarily hurt, either). Starting Strength, a program with similar lifts to Stronglifts, only gives three mentions of stretching in the entire book.

So, your stretching routine depends on what you're looking to improve. You only mention two performance metrics in your question: sit reach and splits.

For train those two aspects, do a general full body warm-up (doesn't have to be long... 5 minutes is fine), then do sit reaches, one legged sit reaches, splits, split variations, hamstring, and groin stretches.